# Android manual control over camera flash timing

Tags: java, android, c, android-camera2

The Android camera2 API gives you some basic control of the flash and camera (ie preflash or no preflash).  However, I would like to manually set the timing of the flash (how many milliseconds between when the flash starts and the shutter opens).

I know I could increase the delay by putting a flash on a preview frame request, and then capturing on a subsequent request.  However, I want to be able to reduce the delay as well, arbitrarily.

My first thought was to turn off the flash and control the torch/flashlight myself, but I read that when the camera turns on you lose control of the flashlight.

Is there any way to achieve this?  I'm willing to write low-level native code if that's what's required, but I have no experience doing so on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no control for this.

The flash unit is tied directly into the camera processing pipeline and metering algorithms, so all control for flash goes through the camera API.

While you can turn the flash on and off manually while the camera is open (via [CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#FLASH_MODE)), that's synchronized to frame boundaries, and there's no offset control today.